# Iphone calling application

Tags: iphone, ios

Actually i have to develop an application for IPHONE in which my application should response if a user clicks on CALL button even if my application is not in running state.
Plz help if anyone can.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, there's no way anybody can answer this. Entire applications are out of scope for Stack Overflow questions. Read up on Apple's documentation, follow tutorials, start coding and testing. When you have a specific problem with your code, that's when it's appropriate to come to us. Please also consider re-reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

> i have to develop an application for IPHONE in which my application
>   should response if a user clicks on CALL button even if my application
>   is not in running state.

Probably the best you can do is to provide a [call event handler](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCallCenter/callEventHandler) using the Core Telephony framework. As noted in the docs, that won't wake up your app or let it respond immediately when a call changes state, but it will notify your app of the change when the app does wake up. Of course, that requires that the user has run your app at some point in the past and that your app is still in the suspended state. If your app isn't running or suspended, there's no way for you to even find out about calls that were made.

As far as I know, there's no bulletproof way using public API for your app to track all calls or insert itself into the calling process. I fully expect that such a thing is possible if you're able to make the right deal with Apple and/or the various network carriers, but that's well beyond the capacity of a typical iOS developer.

Comment: I find really surprising how people ask this knowing the extremely closed and restrictive apple environment.